# how to find white pixel with lowest location?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My question is how can I find one point in the lowest point of this image?
I know the x coordinate of this point. but, I want to find the y coordinate of that point as well.[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

edited: the following code is to show the lowest point in the image.

```
nz = np.argwhere(res)
Y, X = nz[0]

cv2.circle(image, (Y, X ), 2, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.imshow('result',res)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**but the problem is that after running the code the point does not appear in my original image.**

Answer (score 1):

You can find the coordinates of all non-zero values with

```
nz = numpy.argwhere(img)
```

if you want the first just use

```
y, x = nz[0]
```

if you want the last then use

```
y, x = nz[-1]
```

Your image however is not binary and there are many grayscale values, including "almost black" and "almost white". What do you mean with "lowest point"?

To find the first value bigger than 128 for example you can do

```
y,x = numpy.argwhere(img > 128)[0]
```

and I get this output...

[image]

Comment: to @6502, how can I show the point in the image? please look at the edited post. It does not show anything in the image.

Comment: @programmer: the image is not black/white... so you need to add first some sort of thresholding to decide which pixels are foreground and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading in grayscale or the image itself is grayscale my guess would be:

```
values = cv2.imread('img',0)
# I am taking greater than 100, as opposed to 255 as the values may not be exactly 255
y_coord = max(np.where(values > 100)[1])
```

And if you are working with binary image then replace the condition to `values == 1`

Comment: Hi, I  tried this one,but I am getting following error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "  y_coord = max(np.where(values> 0)[1])
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

"

Answer (score 1):

First, the lowest point is the point with maximum y. Since OpenCV images are stored in arrays like `y, x, color`, then you need to find the point with the biggest 0th coordinate. It seems, that `numpy.argwhere` returns already sorted result, but the documentation doesn't guarantee that.

```
nz = np.argwhere(res)
# to guarantee the sorting. 
nz = list(nz).sort(key=lambda point: point[0])
assert nz, "No white points"

# take the last point, the point with biggest Y
Y, X = nz[-1]
```

Then, the drawing part. Your image is in grayscale, so all the points you are trying to draw on it, will be drawn in white. It will be impossible to distinguish the drawn point, from the previously present To draw points I suggest converting the image to `BGR`, and the draw colorful points.

```
image_color = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
# note the order, (X, Y)
cv2.circle(image_color, (X, Y), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
# make sure you show the image, where you have drawn a circle
cv2.imshow('result',image_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: To @Dima Mironov, what is return here? "if not nz:
    print("No white points")
    return
# take the last point, the point with biggest Y
Y, X = nz[-1]"  Why I am getting an error for the return?

Comment: I put else: instead of return, the answer that shows is the top part it does not give a correct answer.

Comment: @programmer. This return is analogous to assert, it makes sure we are not trying to take `[-1]` element from an empty array, if all your pixels are black. Is it Python 2 or 3 you are using? Maybe the error is with print being not a function? Proper error handling depends on the context, of course.

Comment: File "image.py", line 217
    return
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: @programmer, fixed that, changed to assertion